# О подсчёте суммы по элементам списка

Tags: python

```
for h in range(0,len(a)):
    tot =0
    tot = tot+ a[h]
print (tot)
```

машина выдаёт 6, список - 1,2,3,4,6, явно, что-то не так. почему машина не считает верную сумму? спасибо

Comment: `sum(a)` - старайтесь сразу думать "по-питонски"

Comment: поддерживаю @entithat - не используйте циклы там где их можно не использовать - `tot = sum(a)` - выглядет гораздо понятнее, элегантнее  и работает, к тому же, быстрее чем явный цикл. Кроме того в этом коде очень сложно сделать ошибку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы при каждой итерации цикла обнуляете счётчик, видимо вы планировали сделать так

```
tot = 0
for h in range(0,len(a)):
    tot = tot + a[h]
print (tot)
```

Comment: ааа, спасибо большое. потому что считалка локальная прм? ну да.. глупо сделал